# TextFields devision and showing in label

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

There are two textfields, i need that would introduced number in first textfield divided by introduced number in second textfield and showed result in separate label. Help please!

Comment: may be you can try do it yourself and have problems in code?

Comment: What have you tried? have a go at it, and when you hit a snag, post here about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the following should work:

```
label3.text = String(Float(label1.text) / Float(label2.text))
```

You take the text in `label1`, convert it to a float, do the same for `label2`, do the conversion and then convert it back to a string. Then take that string and set it as the text of `label3`.

(Note: The reason I chose to cast to `Float` and not to `Int` is because you will lose any remainder from the division. If there is no chance of a remainder, or if it is not important, then I would suggest using `Int`)

Comment: I tried to do it, but it's showing error.  Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Comment: I'm asking not because I'm lazy, I'm asking because I tried many ways and all were unsuccessful

Comment: I would think explanation points after both `label1.text` and `label2.text`. This is because the way that you are using it, I don't think that the text fields can be `nil`.